# Counting e's in a string, using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I've been given an assignment from my department and, no matter how much research I'm conducting on this, I just can't seem to come up with a code which will actually run. Here's the outline:

```
"""Count the e's in a string, using for loop.

Test data (you should add more):
input: 'Every e please.'  output: 5

Params: s (string)
Returns: (int) #e in s, either lowercase or uppercase
"""
enter code here
```

Could anyone help me out with this? Only for loops can be used to come up with a code.

Comment: You should at least *attempt* your own homework before cheating on it. You might learn something! You claim to have done research, so where's your implementation?

Comment: Trust me, I've been trying for close to a week man, and I'm still stuck with the first one. I'm freaking out about it. Being a freshman who's never written a single line of code is hard.

Comment: a = ('E, e')
for c in s:
    if c in a:
        return True
return False

print (eCount ('Every e please'))

Comment: There were other codes that I tried using, but I didn't save those.

Comment: Then [edit] to include that in your question. It's not clear why you thought that attempt would work; if you are stuck you should talk to the course staff, not just dump it on the internet.

Comment: @jonrsharpe was I right to dupehammer that one?